# If $S_{n}/\sqrt{n}$ admits a normal distribution, show that $P\Big(|S_{n}|\geq 2\sqrt{n\log n}\Big)\leq Cn^{-2}.$

Tags: probability-theory, proof-verification, normal-distribution

I am working on this exercise:

> Suppose $X_{n}$ is standard normal. Prove that $S_{n}/\sqrt{n}\stackrel{d}{=}X_{1}$, and that for every $x>0$, $$(x^{-1}-x^{-3})e^{-x^{2}/2}\leq\int_{x}^{\infty}e^{-t^{2}/2}dt\leq x^{-1}e^{-x^{2}/2}.$$ Deduce that, for some absolute constant $C>0$, and every sufficient large $n$, we have $$P\Big(|S_{n}|\geq 2\sqrt{n\log n}\Big)\leq Cn^{-2}.$$

I have proved everything except for the last part. I had some attempts but I was stuck in the end.

Before writing down my attempt, I have a question which is essential to this exercise. In this exercise, I only proved that $S_{n}/\sqrt{n}$ has the same distribution as $X_{1}$, which implies $$P(S_{n}/\sqrt{n}\leq a)=P(X_{1}\leq a)$$ for all $a$, and the same can be applied to $\geq$.

But this exercise asks me about the distribution of $|S_{n}|$, so it seems that I need to split the probability into $$P\Big(|S_{n}|\geq 2\sqrt{n\log n}\Big)=P\Big(S_{n}/\sqrt{n}\geq 2\sqrt{\log n}\ \text{or}\ S_{n}/\sqrt{n}\leq -2\sqrt{\log n}\Big),$$ but how could I split out this probability? Is that true we have $$P\Big(|S_{n}|\geq 2\sqrt{n\log n}\Big)=P\Big(S_{n}/\sqrt{n}\geq 2\sqrt{\log n}\Big)+P\Big(S_{n}/\sqrt{n}\leq -2\sqrt{\log n}\Big)?$$

I have some attempt of $P\Big(S_{n}/\sqrt{n}\geq 2\sqrt{\log n}\Big)$.

**Here is my attempt:**

Since $S_{n}/\sqrt{n}$ has the same distribution as $X_{1}$, we have $$P\Big(S_{n}/\sqrt{n}\geq 2\sqrt{\log n}\Big)=P\Big(X_{1}\geq 2\sqrt{\log n}\Big)=(2\pi)^{-1/2}\int_{2\sqrt{\log n}}^{\infty}e^{-t^{2}/2}dt,$$ where the last equality is using the density function of standard normal distribution.

Then, by inequality in the exercise, we have 
\begin{align*}
(2\pi)^{-1/2}\int_{2\sqrt{\log n}}^{\infty}e^{-t^{2}/2}dt&\leq(2\pi)^{-1/2}\dfrac{1}{2\sqrt{\log n}}\exp(-2\log n)\\
&=\dfrac{(2\pi)^{-1/2}}{2}n^{-2}\dfrac{1}{\sqrt{\log n}}.
\end{align*}

Now, for $n$ large enough, $\sqrt{\log n}\leq \sqrt{n^{2}}=n$, and thus $$\text{the above}\leq \dfrac{(2\pi)^{-1/2}}{2}n^{-3}\leq \dfrac{(2\pi)^{-1/2}}{2}n^{-2}.$$

Is my attempt correct? and what should I do with $|S_{n}|$?

Thank you!

**Edit 1:**

The above has a mistake that while $\sqrt{\log n}\leq \sqrt{n^{2}}=n$ is true, it it in the denominator.

So I will just use $\log n\geq 1$ for all $n\geq e$, and thus $$P\Big(S_{n}/\sqrt{n}\geq 2\sqrt{\log n}\Big)\leq \dfrac{(2\pi)^{-1/2}}{2}n^{-2}\dfrac{1}{\sqrt{\log n}} \leq \dfrac{(2\pi)^{-1/2}}{2}n^{-2}.$$

Therefore, $$P\Big(|S_{n}|\geq 2\sqrt{n\log n}\Big)=2P\Big(S_{n}/\sqrt{n}\geq 2\sqrt{\log n}\Big)\leq \dfrac{(2\pi)^{-1/2}}{4}n^{-2}.$$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, your attempt seem correct.

So is your splitting, since the events $\left\{S_{n}/\sqrt{n}\geq 2\sqrt{\log n}\right\}$ and $\left\{ S_{n}/\sqrt{n}\leq -2\sqrt{\log n}\right\}$ are disjoint. Then by symmetry of $S_n/\sqrt n$, $$P\Big(\left\lvert S_{n}/\sqrt{n}\right\rvert\geq 2\sqrt{\log n}\Big)=2P\Big(S_{n}/\sqrt{n}\geq 2\sqrt{\log n}\Big).$$

Comment: and the symmetry is because we are in the standard normal distribution? so it is symmetric about 0?

Comment: Exactly. ${}{}{}$

Comment: and is that generally true $P(X\geq x)=\int_{x}^{\infty}f(x)dx?$ I used this in my proof, otherwise I need $P(X\geq x)=-P(X\leq x)$ and it will be more complicated....

Comment: Yes, $P(X\geq x)=\int_{x}^{\infty}f(t)dt$ is true when $X$ has a density $f$.

Comment: good! Thank you so much!

Comment: Ah... I found something is wrong... $\log n\leq n^{2}$, but it is the denominator....

Comment: I know, I will just use $\log n>1$, and we are done